# Do i have to add realm to the app dependency if i am using it in a library module

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am want to use realm to store some data in my application, I am using kotlin and I followed the tutorial on mongodb website to set up my application : https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/

I was able to make it work, the problem is that I have a library module where I use realm and everything is set up, and I import this library as aar in an other project to build my app. The problem is that my app doesn't seem to find the realm dependency :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/realm/RealmConfiguration$Builder;
```

I have used other lib before and I only had to declare the dependency once inside my library module then importe the aar inside my app. But here realm work as a plugin as I had to add : `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.8.0"` and `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` to respectively my project and my module to test it.
Do I have to also add those in my app or there is a way to importe those dependencies with my library?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this dependency to your library project:

```
api 'io.realm:realm-android-library-object-server:10.8.1'
```